# How to insert data into MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose. I've two tables into db.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        email:    { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    { collection: 'users' }
    
)



const model = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema)

const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'hahaha' },
        balance:  { type: Number, required: true }
    },
    { collection: 'accounts' }
    
)


module.exports.UserSchema = model
module.exports.AccountSchema = model
```

As you can see the first collection contains `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`). The second collection represents a bank account, related to a specific `user`. So, it has two fields: `user` (foreign key) and `balance` ($100, i.e.). First question: is my code correct to accomplish this task?
Second question: how can I insert data into the `AccountSchema`?
I obviously want to insert data only if the `user` exists into `Userschema`. I think that this doesn't work:

```
const Schema = require('./model/db')
app.post('/api/addaccount', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, balance } = req.body

    try {
        const response = await Schema.AccountSchema.create({
            username,
            balance
        })
        console.log('User account successfully: ', response)
        res.json({status : "ok"})

    } catch (error) {

        throw error
    }   
})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. You've to query the `User` model first to check if any user exists with this username. If yes, you'll continue to store data in the `Account` model, if not you'll return a response something like `user doesn't exist`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).